# How does ASP.NET engine know which button was clicked on the client's end?

Tags: asp.net, onclick

If i have two buttons in an aspx page that postback and if i have the corresponding click handlers in the code behind, how does ASP.NET wire up the correct server side handler(in the code behind) with the client side click event? Is there something obvious i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net pages register javascript for that. when you pass the ID of the control as the `eventTarget`, it will call the correct logic.

```
__doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument)
```

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/

Answer (score 1):

Every aspx control has an ID which is passed back.

Comment: When you submit a form through a submit button, does the id also go in the POST request?

Comment: Yes, you get information about the control that caused the postback through Request["__EVENTTARGET"], and the arguments passed through __EVENTARGUMENT